# NULLIF() function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm facing problem with nullif (). please see below three scenarios:

scenario 1:

```
declare @val  money
declare @pctg money
select  @val = 0.00

select @pctg = nullif(@val,'')
select @pctg  
go
```

In first scenario if I pass 0 to variable @val then @pctg value calculated as NULL. @pctg variable further used to other calculations and it resulting to null result.

To resolve the problem in scenario 1 I have implemented scenario 2:

```
declare @val  money
declare @pctg money
select  @val = 0.00

select @pctg = nullif(convert(varchar,@val),'')
select @pctg  
go
```

this will now return expected 0 and calculation is also fine. But now I have performed one more test with empty string as mentioned in scenario 3:

```
declare @val  money
declare @pctg money
select  @val = ''

select @pctg = nullif(CONVERT(varchar,@val),'')
select @pctg  
go
```

Here I'm expecting to return null value but it will return 0 and my test get failed because on empty string I need final value as null.

can someone please help as the solution of scenario 2 get failed in scenario 3.

I need one solution which will handle all these three scenario.

Comment: Why are you comparing a `money` datatype value to an empty string in the first place?

Comment: Yes, it's not an empty string, it gets converted to a money. Try this : `declare @val money 
declare @pctg money 
select @val = ''
SELECT @val
`

Comment: I can't change the data type. This is what I have as limitation because this data type used in further calculation. you can say it's a design time problem but really this is what I have as limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nothing to do with `Nullif()` function. Since you are checking with numeric (Money) type variable, empty string (`''`) gets implicitly converted to same type. On SQL Server, you can convert an empty string to a numeric type. Even though you are expecting an error, your output will be `0`.

To understand what is happening, try this **[fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/25049)**:

```
SELECT CONVERT(money, '') X, CONVERT(int, '') Y

--Results
  X  | Y
0.00 | 0
```

Comment: Hi Kaf, I agree with you. you are absolutely correct. Is there any way I can force fully change this 0 value to null.

Comment: What do you want to check? What value of `@val` should make `@pctg` equal to null?

Comment: I want to handle 0 as well empty string ('', '  '). If from UI user pass 0 then zero should get returned and in case of empty string it should return null value.

Comment: I think it would be better if you do it on your code rather than passing it to sql server.

Comment: if I use (as in scenario 1) Select '@pctg' = nullif(value, '') and  pass 0 to it then it will return NULL. variable '@pctg' used in further formula say @test = value * test1. Thus in this case it will return final value as null. To solve this I have used scenario 2 (as mentioned in my original question). Scenario 2 resolve the NULL value problem. But if in any case end user pass empty string ('','  ') to '@value' then it will be calculated with 0 value which is incorrect as In this case I want to show NULL value. I want to handle this situations.

Comment: **Check user typed value before converting it to Money type**. (i.e. Check the string for empty string) If you convert/assign it to a numeric type it will convert `''` to `0` and you'll never get expected results.

Comment: I have used follwoing code to handle all three scenario and it is working fine as my expectations: case when isnumeric(nullif(@pctg,'')) = 1 then convert (money, nullif(@pctg,'')) else null end;

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
select isNull((r1.postalcode),600006) postalcode, r2.postalcode
from ((select nullif(postalcode,' ') postalcode from customer )) r1 
right outer join customer r2 
on r1.postalcode=r2.PostalCode
```